# Can't use {HTTP_HOST} for multiple rewrite rules in web.config file with GoDaddy Hosting - IIS 7.0

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7, web-config, url-rewrite-module, http-host

I came across a weird issue while creating a few rewrite rules for my website which is hosted by GoDaddy. I'm able to create one rewrite rule using the `{HTTP_HOST}` or `{SERVER_NAME}` variables, but at the time of adding a second rule, it looks like the `{HTTP_HOST}`/`{SERVER_NAME}` doesn't return a value (I guess), so my code fails.

After a small mistake, I found a work around to the issue (which I will add at the bottom). I'm asking this question because I would like to:

- Understand the reason of this behavior
- Know if this is happening to    someone else
- Find out if my approach is wrong or if I'm missing something for
  it to work

Due to this issue, I decided to clear my whole web.config file for testing purposes and have only the rewrite rules. I tried multiple changes, but I can't recall all of them at this time, so I will add as much as I remember.

## Issue

This code works

```xml
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Mask myFile.xml" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <!-- This rule always -->
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/myFile.xml" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/SiteDependentFiles/{HTTP_HOST}/new_myFile.xml"  appendQueryString="false"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

This code doesn't (see notes inside code)

```xml
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Mask myFile.xml" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <!-- This rule works on and off. When it doesn't work, it returns a 404 (Not found) error -->
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/myFile.xml" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/SiteDependentFiles/{HTTP_HOST}/new_myFile.xml"  appendQueryString="false"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="Mask thisThingy.txt" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <!-- This rule never works and it returns a 500 (Internal Server) error -->
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/thisThingy.txt" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/SiteDependentFiles/{HTTP_HOST}/new_thisThingy.txt"  appendQueryString="false"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

This is what I get in the "detail report"

404.0 Error - Details

- **Module:** IIS Web Core
- **Notification:** MapRequestHandler
- **Handler:** StaticFile
- **Error Code:** 0x80070002
- **Requested URL:** http://mySiteName.com:80/myFile.xml
- **Physical Path:** D:\Hosting\123123123\html\myFile.xml
- **Logon Method:** Anonymous
- **Logon User:** Anonymous

500.0 Error - Details

- **Module:** ServerSideIncludeModule
- **Notification:** ExecuteRequestHandler
- **Handler:** SSI-html
- **Error Code:** 0x80070002
- **Requested URL:** http://mySiteName.com:80/thisThingy.txt
- **Physical Path:** D:\Hosting\123123123\html\thisThingy.txt
- **Logon Method:** Anonymous
- **Logon User:** Anonymous

Now, if change `{HTTP_HOST}` for a string in the second rule **only**, both rules start working:

```xml
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/SiteDependentFiles/StaticFolderName/new_thisThingy.txt"  appendQueryString="false"/>
```

#### Please note:

I also tried using a different `patternSyntax` option, `Redirect` instead of `Rewrite`, `stopProcessing="false"`, used `{SERVER_NAME}` instead of `{HTTP_HOST}`, added `<clear />` before first rule, but nothing changes. Same behavior.

## Workaround

Always add a rule *condition* with `{HTTP_HOST}` to be able to use `{SERVER_NAME}` as variable for rule's *action*

```xml
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear /> 
                <!--
                    ALWAYS ADD <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*" /> TO BE 
                    ABLE TO USE {SERVER_NAME} MULTIPLE TIMES. (GODADDY ISSUE)
                -->
                <rule name="Mask myFile.xml" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/myFile.xml" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/SiteDependentFiles/{SERVER_NAME}/new_myFile.xml"  appendQueryString="false"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="Mask thisThingy.txt" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/thisThingy.txt" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/SiteDependentFiles/{SERVER_NAME}/new_thisThingy.txt"  appendQueryString="false"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

#### Please note:

- I'm using `{HTTP_HOST}` and `{SERVER_NAME}`, but using only `{HTTP_HOST}`could work. I can't test this right now.

## Thank you